# DQL - dOCUMENTUM - Replacing one acl with another

Tags: documentum-dql

How can i write a dql/iapi script to replace a specific acl in a specific location?

update dm_sysobject object

set acl_name="new_acl"

set acl_domain = 'domain"

where acl_name='old_acl' WHERE FOLDER('/xxxxxxxxxxxxx', descend)

Answer (score 0):

> update dm_sysobject object
> set acl_name="new_acl"
> set acl_domain = 'domain"
> where acl_name='old_acl' ***AND*** FOLDER('/xxxxxxxxxxxxx', descend)